# How to count the length of array within an object?

Tags: arrays, perl, twitter

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Net::Twitter;
use JSON;
use LWP::Simple;
use XML::Bare;
use Data::Dumper;

# keys for twitter
$consumer_key = "key";
$consumer_secret = "key"; 
$token = "key-key";
$token_secret = "key";

# As of 13-Aug-2010, Twitter requires OAuth for authenticated requests
my $nt = Net::Twitter->new(
    traits   => [qw/API::RESTv1_1/],
    # traits   => [qw/API::Search/],
    consumer_key        => $consumer_key,
    consumer_secret     => $consumer_secret,
    access_token        => $token,
    access_token_secret => $token_secret,   
);

$UserID = 46562311;


my $IDs = $nt->friends_ids({user_id => $UserID});
print Dumper $IDs->{ids};
```

The output is:

$VAR1 = [
          1243478918,
          472407213,
          1152523333,
          18080969,
          36843988,
          24467012,
          322990625,
          15492359,
          2244340904,
          22938914,
          151180133,
          58545637,
          62513246,
          28412286,
          5746452,
          17104751,
          1636590253,
          25073877,
          8161232,
          2384071,
          13,
          93957809,
          22330739,
          44196397,
          132961448,
          754500,
          94384796,
          59604041,
          386854967,
          15485441,
          190617492,
          226237599,
          114485232,
          190486752,
          18645153,
          326350862,
          546915948,
          1927794380,
          244360712,
          254674228,
          43593,
          17242168,
          17268874,
          117539435,
          116737145,
          326642243,
          1010165784,
          19583340,
          7936522,
          166739404,
          50374439,
          593893034,
          1244526223,
          783214,
          382267114,
          299743215,
          16129880,
          20536157,
          17006157,
          2249234689,
          26761757,
          17919972,
          2244994945,
          1526228120,
          11348282,
          14159148,
          50393960,
          1339835893,
          409685881,
          2469260288,
          1012494116,
          270816968,
          813286,
          2546660556,
          518542127,
          794611698,
          108962082,
          1626691956,
          734314441,
          20351217,
          1692371666,
          774980724,
          865699670,
          1958038938,
          826539409,
          805891104,
          14749606,
          391858548,
          26693596
        ];

How do I count the length of this array? I used "length $IDs->{ids}" but it only gave me 21 which is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`scalar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/scalar.html) builtin function:

```
print scalar @{ $IDs->{ids} };
```

It forces it's argument to be interpreted in scalar context. And as you know array in scalar context is evaluated to it's length.

Comment: Thanks, but "print scalar @{ $IDs->{ids} };" gives me "1" as result. Weird.

Comment: @NoahSong: I'm getting 89. It returns 1, but prints 89.

Comment: @choroba Oh thanks! It seems I just reached the rate limit..